I've written the code below however it's returning an syntax error and I can't figure out what's wrong
inner join [@PM_CMS_VLD] pm_cms_vld on pm_ocms.DocEntry=pm_cms_vld.DocEntry and CONVERT(date, year ({?Date To}) = year ({?Date To}) >= pm_cms_vld.U_From AND CONVERT(date, year ({?Date To}) = year ({?Date To}) <= pm_cms_vld.U_To
Help please!
I though it would work and allow me chose the year.
